# Is there a way to use ebgaramond lining numbers in math mode in pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, ebgaramond

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{EBGaramond}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{EBGaramond}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}...
```

Can we use these commands to use Eb garamond in math in pdf latex? if possible, what do i have to write instead of EBGaramond in the commands.

Comment: Note also http://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond-maths but it will give you more than just the numbers in EB Garamond.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\begin{document}
123 $123$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I waited for a few days but no reply came. Then I tried to find another ways. This approval is maybe late, sorry, but i notice this now.