# Eulervm: Use digits from other font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, ebgaramond, eulervm

Is there a ways to the digits from another font for math? Ideally I would like to use `ebgaramond` as a main font and the old style figures form `MinionPro` for math since the old style digit `1` of garamond looks like a `I`. I want this because the euler-digits are way too large to be used with `ebgaramond`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[]{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor § sit amet
\item 123
\item $123$
\end{itemize}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If you don't have MinionPro installed I would also appreciate and example that shows how the digits form another (default) latex font can be used.

Comment: Generally, the use of OSF in math mode is not encouraged.  Do I understand that is nonetheless your intent?

Comment: ebgaramond has only osf. If you have a better option that looks nice with ebgaramond and eulervm, then you are welcome to post an answer. Maybe MinionPro with lining figures.

Comment: `\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}`  Does that suit?

Comment: You can change the digits in math mode.  In text mode it is virtually impossible.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It does look good. If I can keep my osf in normal text mode, then perfect.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The solution is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146603/is-there-a-way-to-use-ebgaramond-lining-numbers-in-math-mode-in-pdflatex

Comment: I have another *possible* solution: `\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\fontfamily{EBGaramond-\ebgaramond@figurealign OsF}\selectfont}
\makeatother`

Comment: Strangely, this only seems to produce the desired result if `\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}` is also loaded, which in your case, it is.  Clearly, egreg's answer is the canonical way to achieve the result.

Comment: I think the solution to my original answer would be to use `\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{n}`, but replace `EBGaramond-LF` by the Minion Pro osf. Where do I get the name for this?

Comment: On Page 7 of ftp://ftp.fau.de/ctan/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf, you will see that it could be `MinionPro-OsF` or `MinionPro-TOsF`, depending on the desired encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is to use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[]{ebgaramond}
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{MinionPro-TOsF}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}
```

As Steven B. Segletes noted, it would be better to lining figures. The following uses EBGaramond's LF in math.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[]{ebgaramond}
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}
```