Use different fonts in math mode
I would like to use two different font in math mode, depending on the caracter:

letters in fourier
numbers in sansmathfonts
Is it possible in an easy way ?

Edit:
Here is a MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}


\begin{document}

$ABC \ abc \ 123$

\end{document}

I found two topics on that subject, but I didn't how to transpose their solution to my problem
LaTeX: use different fonts in math mode
two fonts in math mode

Please provide a MWE we can start from…

BTW, I guess you want something automatic rather than using a command to switch between fonts?

Assuming that's possible, yes.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313875/36296 (replace EBGaramond-LF with the font you'd like to use )

It worked for me using \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{xcmss}{m}{n}
