# EB Garamond numbers in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, font-encodings, ebgaramond, math-fonts

I'm trying to get the ebgaramond-maths package to work properly in XeLaTeX. Everything seems to work well except for the numbers. The numbers in math mode still show up in the default Computer/Latin Modern typeface.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{anyfontsize} 

\begin{document}
123 $123 ABC$
\end{document}
```

This code gives the following output with no warnings. As you can see, the numbers in math mode aren't set in EB Garamond.

[image]

If I remove the first line, to compile with pdfLaTeX, the package works fine and the numbers are in EB Garamond.

[image]

I think this has something to do with the encoding of the numbers. I have tried the declaring the math symbols manually using [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157067), but that didn't work in XeLaTeX (though it did work with pdfLaTeX). I also tried using the mathspec package, but that clashed with ebgaramond-maths.

Does anyone know how to get ebgaramond-maths with EB Garamond numbers in math mode using XeLaTeX?

Comment: Note that `ebgaramond-maths` is NOT designed for use with XeTeX or LuaTeX and such usage is entirely unsupported. That said, it should work if the traditional TeX maths configuration is left alone. That is, provided that letters and so on are taken from the OT1 type1 fonts and not from the Unicode opentype ones. But if it does not, it is not a bug. Also, it is not suitable for arbitrary mathematics. Only a limited subset of maths can reasonably be expected to look passably satisfactory, even with pdfTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
123 $123 ABC$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr No, I'll uncomment it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the failure of `ebgaramond` with the `type1` option is now expected?

Comment: @cfr There's no font definition file for the TU or EU1 encoding, so the text font is substituted. I'm not sure what the `type1` option is supposed to do with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX.

Comment: Since the `fontspec` package needs to be loaded, is there an advantage to running `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` instead of executing `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`?

Comment: @Mico I'd say yes. It doesn't just do `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`.

Comment: I think it is supposed to use the type1 fonts rather than the opentype. At least, I assume so. However, the package doesn't seem to have any documentation to speak of, so it is hard to be certain.